# Known issues with SQL Server 2005 in Flyway

Tags: sql-server-2005, flyway

Flyway supports only SQL Server 2008 and later according to: [Supported Databases](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/) 
 (2012-11-28)

Are there any known issues using SQL Server 2005 and Flyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the docs:

Older versions may work, but they have not been tested.

I am currently not aware of any reports detailing issues. Please give it a try and let me know. I don't expect anything major to show up.